# AsyncResult hangs in unexpected cases in fit_generator of tensorflow's keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, asynchronous, keras, multiprocessing

This is a copy-paste of an [issue I posted on the tensorflow Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34456).

**System information**

- Have I written custom code: yes
- OS Platform and Distribution: Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- TensorFlow installed from: pip
- TensorFlow version: 2.0.0b1
- Python version: 3.6.8
- CUDA/cuDNN version: V10.0.130
- GPU model and memory: Quadro P5000 (16GB)

**Describe the current behavior**

I have a very complicated model solving an image-to-image problem. I also use a custom callback which at some point generates some noise using `numpy`.
When I use `fit_generator` on this model, it manages to do the first epoch, then on the second, third or fourth it hangs at the beginning of the epoch. I managed to see where the problem was happening, and it happens here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L875
Basically, if I put a timeout on the second `get` it times out after a few successful epochs (sometimes just one). There is no error thrown out so I don't know why it hangs. Furthermore, if I debug at that point in code, I can just execute the function synchronously and everything will work just fine.

**Code to reproduce the issue**

I didn't manage to get a minimal example using `fit_generator` (basically it relies too much on me using my model which is complex). However, I have a minimal example which reproduces the bug when I mimic the [`model_iteration`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L41) function.
You need to install the following to make it work: `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1 numpy tqdm`

```py
# imports
import time

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import callbacks as cbks
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training_utils
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import data_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import generic_utils
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

# helper function (taken from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L500)
def _make_enqueued_generator(generator,
                             workers=1,
                              use_multiprocessing=False,
                             max_queue_size=10,
                             shuffle=False):    
    enqueuer = data_utils.OrderedEnqueuer(
        generator, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, shuffle=shuffle)
    enqueuer.start(workers=workers, max_queue_size=max_queue_size)
    output_generator = enqueuer.get()
    return output_generator, enqueuer

# My silly callback
class Noise(Callback):
     def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        image_shape = [1, 2**7, 2**7, 1]
        noise = np.random.normal(scale=1.0, size=image_shape)

# My data
batch_size = 8
n_samples_train = 720
x = np.random.rand(n_samples_train, 256, 256, 1)
im_gen_train = ImageDataGenerator().flow(x, batch_size=batch_size)


# My training set up (to mimic https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L41)
data = im_gen_train
steps_per_epoch = int(n_samples_train / batch_size)
epochs = 20
max_queue_size=35
workers=35
use_multiprocessing=True
shuffle=False
initial_epoch=0
mode=1
steps_name='steps'
noise_cb = Noise()
noise_cb.on_train_batch_end = noise_cb.on_batch_end
callbacks=[noise_cb]

generator, enqueuer = _make_enqueued_generator(
    im_gen_train,
    workers=workers,
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
    max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    shuffle=shuffle)

callbacks = cbks.configure_callbacks(
    callbacks,
    Model(),
    do_validation=False,
    epochs=epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    samples=n_samples_train,
    verbose=0,  # Handle ProgBar as part of Callbacks once hooks are ready.
    mode=mode,
)
callbacks._call_begin_hook(mode)

for epoch in tqdm_notebook(range(initial_epoch, epochs)):
    callbacks.on_epoch_begin(epoch, {})

    for step in tqdm_notebook(range(steps_per_epoch), leave=False):
        callbacks._call_batch_hook('train', 'begin', step, {})
        batch_data = next(generator)

        # I don't actually train a model, so I just sleep for this time, this would be the backprop
        time.sleep(0.1)
        callbacks._call_batch_hook('train', 'end', step, {})
```

If you leave it as such, it will hang after about 1, 2, 3, or 4 iterations.
You can comment out the `noise = np.random.normal(scale=1.0, size=image_shape)` line and see that it doesn't hang.

You can also modify tensorflow's source code and timeout [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L875) in the second `get` so you can debug.

Note also that if the sleeping time is not high enough, hanging doesn't appear.

### EDIT

I finally managed to put together a minimal example involving `fit_generator` directly:

```py
# imports
import time

from keras_tqdm import TQDMNotebookCallback
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Lambda, concatenate
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.utils import  Sequence


# My silly callback
class Noise(Callback):
     def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        image_shape = [1, 2**7, 2**7, 1]
        noise = np.random.normal(scale=1.0, size=image_shape)

# my metrics
def keras_psnr(y_true, y_pred):
    max_pixel = tf.math.reduce_max(y_true)
    min_pixel = tf.math.reduce_min(y_true)
    return tf.image.psnr(y_true, y_pred, max_pixel - min_pixel)

def keras_ssim(y_true, y_pred):
    max_pixel = tf.math.reduce_max(y_true)
    min_pixel = tf.math.reduce_min(y_true)
    return tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, max_pixel - min_pixel)

# My data
class MergedGenerators(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *generators):
        self.generators = generators
        # TODO add a check to verify that all generators have the same length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.generators[0])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return tuple([generator[index] for generator in self.generators])

batch_size = 8
n_samples_train = 720
size = 256
x = np.random.rand(n_samples_train, size, size, 1)
im_gen_train_1 = ImageDataGenerator().flow(x, batch_size=batch_size, seed=0)
im_gen_train_2 = ImageDataGenerator().flow(x, batch_size=batch_size, seed=0)
im_gen_train = MergedGenerators(im_gen_train_1, im_gen_train_2)

# my fake model
im = Input((None, None, 1))
conv = Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same')(im)
conv = Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same')(conv)
conv = Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same')(conv)
ident = Lambda(lambda x: x)(conv)
model = Model(im, ident)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[keras_psnr, keras_ssim])
print(model.summary(line_length=150))

# My training set up
noise_cb = Noise()
noise_cb.on_train_batch_end = noise_cb.on_batch_end
tqdm_cb = TQDMNotebookCallback(metric_format="{name}: {value:e}")
tqdm_cb.on_train_batch_begin = tqdm_cb.on_batch_begin
tqdm_cb.on_train_batch_end = tqdm_cb.on_batch_end
model.fit_generator(
    im_gen_train,
    steps_per_epoch=int(n_samples_train / batch_size), 
    epochs=20,
    max_queue_size=35,
    workers=35,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    shuffle=False,
    callbacks=[noise_cb, tqdm_cb],
    verbose=0,
)
```

It's not very bare, but at least it's directly usable (you just need to install `keras-tqdm` additionally).

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L522 this might be known at tensorflow now.

Comment: following discussions with [Thomas Moreau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2642845/thomas-moreau), we think this is due to a problem in `numpy`'s random module, probably https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9248, I will let him answer the question when he has time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in version 2.1.

Another fix would be to use the [new random number generation API of `numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/generator.html) as advised [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9248#issuecomment-522340824). That changes the line `noise = np.random.normal(scale=1.0, size=image_shape)` to `noise = np.random.default_rng().normal(scale=1.0, size=image_shape)`. This fix works even in version 2.0.

This is a copy-paste of the answer I gave on Github.